# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'RL' was corrupted

Tags: c++, stack

my problem is when I run my program it tells me that "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'RL' was corrupted."

```
#include<iostream>    
double current(double Eth, double Rth, double RL[], int j);    
double power(double I[], int k, double RL[], int j);    
int main()
{
    using namespace std;    
    double Eth, Rth, RL[100], I[100], P[100], Pmax;    
    Pmax = 0;    
    cout << "enter the values of Eth and Rth respectively " << endl;
    cin >> Eth >> Rth;
    int j = 0;    
    for (int i = (Rth / 10); i <= Rth * 10; i = i + 0.25)
    {
        RL[j] = i;
        I[j] = current(Eth, Rth, RL, j);
        P[j] = power(I, j, RL, j);
        if (P[j]> Pmax)
            Pmax = P[j];
        j++;
    }
    cout << " the max power =" << Pmax << endl;    
    return 0;    
}
double current(double Eth, double Rth, double RL[], int j)    
{   
    double IL;    
    IL = (Eth / (RL[j] * Rth));    
    return IL;    
}    
double power(double I[], int k, double RL[], int j)    
{   
    double Pow;    
    Pow = I[k] * I[k] * RL[j];    
    return Pow;   
}
```

Comment: Change your title please.

Answer (score 1):

This here:

```
                                    //    v---- here
for (int i = (Rth / 10); i <= Rth * 10; i = i + 0.25)
```

does not work. `i` is an integer, so `i + 0.25` is immediately converted to `int` in the assignment, so `i` does not change. Thus the loop is an infinite loop, and with `j` climbing in every iteration, at some point it runs out of the bounds of the arrays you write to. At that point, the stack around the arrays becomes corrupted.

Possibly this could be solved by making `i` a `double`.